# Rails open source graphic libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphics

I'm looking for an open source library for graphics that would be compatible with a rails 3.2.11 app. I'd like to basically install a few progress bars...maybe there is something in rails already that does this? Perhaps this is a beginner question. Would love any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI is a natural choice here. It has buttons, progress bars, and tons of other icons/effects. There's a Rails gem for the UI that you can find [here](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails).

Answer (score 0):

[Twitter bootstrap](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap) and [bootstrap sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) gem